# How to Redirect with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have issue with page redirection with codeigniter, I want to redirect from http://mywebsite_domain/index.php/home/show/206 , to http://mywebsite_domain/index.php/ar/home/pages/show/206 . And My controller name "pages" in "home" folder
please help me....

Comment: Not clear what you really asking. add your codes that you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Just you have to write some code in routes.php in `application/config/routes.php`.

```
$route['show/(:any)'] = 'ar/home/pages/show/$1';
```

See more at [CodeIgniter - Routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeigniter's URI routing.

refer the below link-
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

In that you can also use Regular Expressions to get generalized URI routing.
routes.php => /application/config/routs.php